# 'Unauthorized' to push images into SSL Artifactory Docker Registry

Tags: ssl, nginx, artifactory, docker-registry

Im sorry if this topic is duplicated, I was not able to find anything similar to this problem.

Our docker clients `v17.X +` (Docker for Mac & Docker for Linux) are unable to push images under a SSL V2 Registry but are successfully authenticated for pushes under an Insecure V2 Registry (CNAME) that serves the same machine. The output is always the same: `unauthorized` even if I `docker login` correctly.

The weird thing is: for our old docker clients (`v1.6`) we are able to login and push Docker images to a secure v2 Docker registry without any problem using the credentials file stored at `~/.dockercfg`. My Nginx appears to be working just fine. Any ideas about what I'm missing here?

_
Im attaching both credentials configuration files, if anyone wants to check:

**Docker client: v.17**
`~/.docker/config.json`

```
{
  "auths" : {
    "https://secure-docker-registry.intranet": {
        "auth": "someAuth",
        "email": "somemail@gmail.com"
    }
  },
  "credsStore" : "osxkeychain"
}
```

Obs: In `Docker for Mac`'s case I tried with 'credsStore' and without it
Obs2: Even allowing `anonymous` to push images, I'm still getting an `unauthorized` for this registry.
Obs3: Logs are not very clean about this problem
Obs4: Artifactory is configured using a LDAP Group

**Docker client: v.1.6.2**
`~/.dockercfg`

```
{
    "secure-docker-registry.intranet": {
        "auth": "someAuth",
        "email": "somemail@gmail.com"
    },
    "insecure-docker-registry.intranet": {
        "auth": "someAuth",
        "email": "somemail@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

**Artifactory Pro's version:** `5.4.2`

Comment: It was a misconfigured attribute in our reserve proxy configuration. Adding the header `Docker-Distribution-API-Version registry/2.0` to our Virtual Host solved the problem.

Comment: For the record, there's no rule against providing an answer to your own question.